# c# class that maps per JSONs hierarchy

Tags: c#, json

NOTE: This is NOT about serialization or deserialization of C# <==> JSON.

This is more about have a C# class that maps 1:1 onto JSON's structure itself. JSON can be either dictionaries (hashes) or arrays plus it can also be nested (eg: JSON objects as 'values' or array elements inside a JSON object). How can I define a C# class that behaves the same way such that it can map 1:1 onto it's JSON 'equivalent' ?

BTW, I do see that .NET 4.5 seems to have 1st class support for JSON (finally!) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.110).aspx. Plus it also seems to  do serialization too. However that's a sealed class, so I can't see it's implementation.

*Use the source Luke!*

**EDIT**:  It seems .NET 4.5 is open sourced. I found a link at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx but can't seem to download the source. Tried 3 times with a corrupt download. Any other source location? It would be best to back-port the JSON class from .NET 4.5 => .NET 4.0

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ will give you a C# class against the JSON

Comment: Dictionary<object,object>  can store whatever you want in there.

Comment: @Habib: That's a useful link but the question is about generic representation like JSON does (see http://www.json.org/). The link creates c# classes for a particular template of JSON.

Comment: @awright18: How can that map to [ 0 ] ?

Comment: @awright18: ok, makes sense. Though in that form you need a lot of external 'glue code' on accessing it. To be fully usable as a 1:1, the final class (inheriting from `Dictionary<object,object>`) would need additional internal logic to map cleanly onto JSON's external primitives (object, array) and into it's internal primitives (string, number, boolean, null). www.json.net's diagrams are really clear on class design.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have any circular references in your class structure, you shouldn't have any issues with JSON mapping.  But there are tools that can help minimize any ambiguity.  Here's a relevant blog post that may help: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/06/json-to-c.html